# How to fetch data in Python from SQL as a list of strings instead of tuples?

Tags: python, sql, python-3.x, sqlite, tuples

I'm trying to get the columns names of an SQLite table, but I'm getting back a list of tuples with the names.

```
cur.execute('''SELECT name FROM PRAGMA_TABLE_INFO(\'Emails\')''') 
   .fetchall())
```

If I print this the output is:

```
[('email',), ('count',)]
```

How can I get the data as list of strings?

Comment: I don't understand how we are supposed to answer the question. The interface requires what it requires. If you want to know why it was designed that way, it would be better to ask the designers.

Comment: Each tuple is a **row**, in this case you have rows with only one column (`name`). Because you used `fetchall()`, you get a list of tuples with all rows, one tuple per row.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can extract the column names out of each tuple to a new list:

```
result = cur.execute("SELECT name FROM PRAGMA_TABLE_INFO('Emails')").fetchall()
columns = [x[0] for x in result]
print(columns)
```

Or, get the column names as a comma separated srring with `GROUP_CONCAT()` and then split it:

```
result = cur.execute("SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(name) FROM PRAGMA_TABLE_INFO('Emails')").fetchone()
columns = str(result[0]).split(",")
print(columns)
```

Output:

```
['email', 'count']
```